# What is wrong in my for loop? (Python 2)

Tags: python-2.7, loops

Here's my code:

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
square_list = []
start_list.sort()
for i in xrange(0,len(start_list)):
  square_list[i]=start_list[i]**2
print square_list
```

The error I get is this:

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Sorry if this question seems silly, I'm a beginner

Comment: why are you using `xrange` and not `range`?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7, and isn't xrange a little quicker than range?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are creating `square_list` as empty, so when you try to store into an element, it isn't there and python errors. Simply change the definition to create a list the same length as `start_list` with zero values:

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
square_list = [0] * len(start_list)
start_list.sort()
for i in xrange(0,len(start_list)):
      square_list[i]=start_list[i]**2
print square_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `append` to add new items to the list:

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
square_list = []
start_list.sort()
for i in xrange(0,len(start_list)):
  square_list.append(start_list[i]**2)
print square_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You  cannot access or modify an element of a list unless the list already has that element.
the following code will give errors:

```
l=[] 
l[0]=4 # error -- element 0 doesn't exist yet, so can't modify it 
print l[2]  # error -- element 2 doesn't exist yet, so can't read
```

In your case you can use append or insert method
[see this article](https://sites.google.com/site/usfcomputerscience/Lists)